# Different semantics between tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn == tcp-syn, tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-syn, tcp[13] == tcp-syn, tcp[13] & tcp-syn != 0

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

I have some doubts about the usage of tcpdump to capture packet based on tcpflags. Are these examples interpreted correctly?

```
'tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn == tcp-syn'
```

tcp-syn is set, but **other** flags can be set.

```
'tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-syn'
```

**only** tcp-syn is set

```
'tcp[13] == 2'
```

**only** tcp-syn is set

```
'tcp[13] & 2 == 2'
```

**only** tcp-syn is set

```
'tcp[13] & 2 !=0'
```

tcp-syn is set, but **other** flags can be set.

Comment: Do you have data to suggest they're not? Otherwise, you're asking 5 questions and you should provide more focus to this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is one mistake in the interpretation, that is:

`'tcp[13] & 2 == 2'`

You wrote:

***only** tcp-syn is set*, but this is wrong.  It's the same as the first example, namely:

`'tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn == tcp-syn'`

so the correct interpretation is:

tcp-syn is set, but **other** flags can be set.

The rest of them seem correct to me.